# Check if the function $f=x[\frac 1 x], x\ne 0$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, continuity

Edit: I got carried away and forgot that the function is not defined at $x=0$, which means its not continuous at $x=0$, thanks for all the answers!

My attempt: check if the function is continuous at $x=0$.
I tried to apply the squeeze theorem: 
$\frac 1 x -1<[\frac 1 x] \le \frac 1 x$ , Multiply all by $x\ne 0$, and i got: 
$1-x<x[\frac 1 x] \le 1$, and this implies that the limit $x\rightarrow 0$ is 1. 
and if the limit at $x=0$ exists and equal to 1, then the side limits when $x\rightarrow 0^+$ or $x\rightarrow 0^-$ both exist and equal, which implies that the function is continuos at $x=0$.

I feel like I have made some mistake, since the floor function can be tricky with limits, It would be appreciated if someone can approve if my work is right or wrong and tell me how to approach these kind of questions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on how you define $f$ at $0$.

Comment: The function is not defined at $x=0$, so what is the point discussing continuity there ? And what about $x\ne0$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hi and thanks for the comment, the $x\ne 0$ was in the definition of the function just so we don't divide by 0. I edited that I messed up on forgetting that its not defined at $x=0$ , thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it — technically your solution is good; indeed supposing that $x>0$, for every $k \le x \le k +1$ the floor function returns $\frac{1}{k+1}$; which besides, the x itself is continuous at 0, and floor is discrete. As a little support, Wolfram approved the answer $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x [(\frac{1}{x})] = 1$$.
where $[x]$ means the floor function of x. And it is true that the function still undefined at 0, but the limit shall be 1. Why? That is due to inequalities above. Either way, there should be some set on which you define the function, then the floor shall return the discrete value ; as long as the first part of the function, viz. x, is not discontinuous at 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really appreciated. so I can say that function is not continuous on $x=0$ since its not defined there, and its a removable discontinuity because I can set $f(0)=1$ and make it continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: I would rather agree than disagree because defining the kind of function on, say, 0 < x < 1; we still get 1 as a return from the floor function. If on - 1<x<0, then the floor function returns values lesser than - 1, meaning that there exists the result of the function work. But still there is problem at 0, not on an interval but at the specific point. Defining f(0)=1 is like fixing discontinuity of sin x / x at x = 0. The limit exists but this is still break point of the first kind. Note that Wolfram gives you complex infinity from [1/0].

Comment: I just checked the graph and how it looks, its crazy with alot of jump discontinuities, but I still think that at $x=0$ specifically we can fix it and make it continuous since both of the limits are equal. what do  you think?

Comment: Disconitnies what you did see were due to the discrete nature of the floor function. The discrete automatically implies discontinuity; for that to be illustrated, look at the integral of [x] over 1<x<3. You see that for every k<x<k+1 (where k = 1 and k = 2), there are two values of floor, so the integral is split into over these subsets. Note that before defining the inequality above and considering subsets, it was just a floor function, a function of x, now it got a number. The fixable nature of discontinuity of the function you looked up is behind smoothness; look at $\frac{\sin x}{x}$

Comment: Yeah I checked the $sinx/ x$ graph now I see what you mean, does this mean I can't just come and say if the two side limits are equal I can fix the point here, because the floor function is discrete and it gets crazy at $x=0$ specifically?

Comment: If one states that two side limits of a function - every function can be regarded as a sequence; for that just put $x = n$ - equals to the same number or, in other words, coincide, then there exist the resultant limit, converging to the number. That automatically means the function be continuous at the given point. Remember $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is even because putting $x = -y$ gives the same function but only of y, so the function should be even. If you look at the left and right limits, you see that they converges to 1. Either does the resultant limit. Your function is seen to be even, though.

Comment: The function is undefined at $x=0$, so it is neither continuous nor discontinuous.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, that is what I said in my answer as well and supported by Wolfram, claiming that both limits exist. The asker would be happy to know about why neither continuous nor discontinuous, although side limits are defined. The most famous question is why $0^0 = 1$. The real answer is Yes and No. So, I believe in some sense, its discontinuity is fixable and for some theory, this function turns out to be suitable. Remember about generalized functions :) Mathematician are cunning people who can make discontinuity continuity...

Comment: @sergeiivanov: existence of the limits is not continuity !! "And it is true that the function still undefined at $0$": absolutely not !!!

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is the answer people need in the post! Continuity is defined by limit, but not essentially is. To answer the question, you would look at $f: U \rightarrow V$. Suppose that the rule according to which we get values belonging $V$, using the function that accepts those of $U$. If this $U$ is displayed onto $V$ one-to-one, besides in boths sides: $V$ to $U$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There is several definitions of continuity. You told that limits are not a definition; however, they are in some cases. In my one-to-one, terminology, there is a guarantee that there exists the reciprocal of a function. But one-to-one means? It means that for each $x$ exits only one $y$. No discontinuities; if there is, the it is not. Is this a good def of break point? Nope. Okay, I can regard my function as a sequence and find a subsequence such that it converges to the same number; put for example $x=n$ and $n=2^m$. You get still 1. The is the same story as $0^0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Putting $y = 1/x$ brings us to the support of your answer. Indeed, the limit is then non-existent. Maybe the substitution does not work; okay, then we go to the def of the floor function, which is the maximum integer n such that $n \le \frac{1}{x}$. Supposing that there exist such number, we have $x \le \frac{1}{n}$. Then $n \cdot \frac{1}{n} = 1$. How can that be? So, I would say that everything depends on what you are going to do with your function. In general, you are right; in particular, you are not.

Comment: "There is several definitions of continuity. You told that limits are not a definition; however, they are in some cases": please show me.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would like to "avoid extended discussions in comments". In the situation, I answer your question directly; namely, in calculus, any function appearing by the formula $y = f(x)$ is said to be continuous on the specific subset $U$ if for all points of $U$ there exists and is finite the limit of $f(x)$. That is continuity! Limits require $\varepsilon-\delta$ to show that $|f(x) - A| < \varepsilon$; $|x - x_0| < \delta$. If our function is $F(x, y) = C$ and no expression $y=f(x)$ is established - guess how we define continuity: double limits. Here begins topology.

Comment: @YvesDaoust topology gives you another more strong definition of continuity, that I writing in the second answer to the question of the post: If we say that a function $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = x_0$, then for a neighbourhood U in the domain of the functions value S, there must be the neighbourhood of $x_0$ P lying in S: $f(P) \subset S$. No limits but neighbourhoods.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Suppose that there is a function $u: X \rightarrow Y$. This one is said to be continuous if the bijection or reflection of $X$ onto $Y$ by $u$ is uniformly one-to-one and in both sides, meaning that the reflection of $Y$ onto $X$ is also uniformly one-to-one. Why is the definition not good? It is good but too general. In order to dispose of the generality we have to introduce the continuity on subset, say, $Q$. Or we change $X$ to more specific one, making the set of value of $u(x)$ more reliable. No limits.

Comment: @sergeiivanov: $0$ is not in the domain, hence this alternative definition brings nothing new.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you are defining $f(0)$ to be $1$. There is a mistake in your argument. When $x<0$ multiplying an inequality by $x$ reverses the inquality. So $\frac  1x -1 \leq [\frac 1 x] \leq \frac  1 x$ becomes $x(\frac  1x -1) \geq [\frac 1 x] \geq x\frac  1 x$ for $x<0$ but you still get the left-hand limit as $1$.

Comment: Ohhh, I got carried away and forgot that the limit must be equal to f(0), it is not defined so this means that its not continuous right?

Comment: @Joseph As it is, it is not defined at $0$ but introducing $f(0)=1$ in the definition of the function would make it continuous.

Comment: Ramar Murthy Ah yeah I get it, It's a removable discontinuity that I can fix by introducting $f(0)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Def of continuity is more severe in topology. Let $f: U \rightarrow V$ and put $f(x) = x * \left[\frac{1}{x}\right]$. Any function is said to be continuous at a point $x=a \in U$ if and only if for a neighborhood N of $f(x)$ in V, there exists the one S of the point such $f(S) \subset N$. I presume the idea has been caught. The function is continuous at the point $x_0$ if there exists neighborhood $f^{-1} (N)$ in V. You see that the function must reflect $U$ onto $V$ and vice versa. In the case, if $y(x) = x \cdot \left[\frac{1}{x}\right]$, then $\frac{y}{x} = \left[\frac{1}{x}\right]$. According to definition above, we must find a neighborhood $f^{-1} (N) $ where N is the neighborhood of $f(x)$ in V, so there exists a neighborhood of the point zero $S$ such that $f(S)$ is a subset of N. We see that we cannot find reciprocal in one-to-one manner. That is where you might think about discontinuity of the function.